# Count from USER_INDEXES and ALL_INDEXES

Tags: oracle

I was trying to execute the following query to get the count of `index` from my schema.

`select count(*) from USER_INDEXES;`  --which gave me a count of `397`

But 
`select count(*) from ALL_INDEXES where table_owner ='MY_SCHEMA';` -- gave me `357`.

What it sounds? Both should be same right?

When checked from `Oracle SQL developer` by counting the indexes myself, gave me `397`

Comment: Are you sure those numbers are correct?  They look backwards to me.  I would expect `ALL_INDEXES` to return more than `USER_INDEXES`.

Comment: @jonearles : Yes.It is correct. I double-checked that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because, the view `ALL_INDEXES` contains all the indexes the current user has the ability to modify. You will not see the LOB index in this view because LOB indexes cannot be renamed, rebuilt, or modified.

While `USER_INDEXES` view contains all the indexes that the user owns. The LOB index will be in this view if the user querying it is the same user that created it.

Comment: Thanks for a new piece of information. So we should go with `USER_INDEXES`.

Comment: @codeforfood, Yeah. Better to go with `USER_INDEXES` view to get the all index details including lob types.

Comment: @Dba, can you please link to the documentation? Can't find this.